# Add enviroment variables during build

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, react-scripts

I am trying to add an evnviroment variable while building my React app

In my `package.json` i have added a script like that:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build:public": "PUBLIC_URL=http://myPublicURL.com/ react-scripts build"
}
```

it should add the `PUBLIC_URL` temp variable and use it during the build but it does not work and i get an error:

```bash
'PUBLIC_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

if I add the variable manually in the `.env` file everything works fine.

I would like to do it without installing additional packages

Comment: That syntax doesn't work on Windows, hence https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: I am using Ubuntu WSL

Comment: "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." is an error message that only occurs on Windows.